# Can't "<-" be used in a where block?

Tags: haskell, where-clause

I'm basically trying to define the path of a given file in the "res" file in the working directory, and what I have done is the following:

```
iZone :: [Char]
iZone = "21.evt"

iZonePath :: String IO
iZonePath = result
 where
  path <- getCurrentDirectory
  result = (path ++ /res/ ++ iZone)
```

However, ghc comlines with

> src/Main.hs:15:8: error:
>
> ```
> parse error on input ‘<-’
>
> Perhaps this statement should be within a 'do' block?    | 15 |
> ```
>
> path <- getCurrentDirectory

What is the reason for that ? Can't I use "<-" *operation* in a "where" block ?

Comment: `<-` is specific to `do`-blocks since they are syntactic sugar for `>>=`. You cannot use it in a `where`-block because `where`-blocks are not in the context of monads.

Comment: @AJFarmar What is special about ">>=" that we can only use it within do blocks ?

Comment: You haven't understood; `do`-blocks are *syntactic sugar* for `>>=` and `>>`, not the other way around. The problem is that `do`-blocks are 'special' (read: monadic), and `where`-blocks are not. Do you understand monads?

Comment: @AJFarmar I haven't studied them.

Comment: I would strongly reccommend studying monads before attempting to use them like you are here. [The LYAH chapters](http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads#getting-our-feet-wet-with-maybe) are good starting points.

Comment: @AJFarmar Thanks for the suggestion, I was planning to study them

Comment: Just to be clear: It is perfectly possible to use `>>=` outside of `do` (in fact it's usually used outside of `do` because, as, AJFarmer said, inside `do` we can just use `<-` as sugar for `>>=`), what isn't possible outside `do` is to use `<-` instead of `>>=`. You could very well write `result = getCurrentDirectory >>= \path -> ...` (though the ... should contain an expression of type `IO String`, not `String` - otherwise that's a type error), but then you could also write the same thing as do block like `result = do path <- ...` and either way you could just get rid of the `where` then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IO monad is designed so to force the programmer choose a specific ordering among side effects.

Assume that this were allowed:

```
foo :: IO ()
foo = do
  putStrLn "1"
  putStrLn x
  putStrLn "2"
  putStrLn x
  putStrLn "3"
 where
  x <- putStrLn "x generated here" >> return "x used here"
```

What would be the output?

Is `x generated here` printed at the very beginning of the `do` block, before the `1` is printed? Just after that?

Is `x generated here` printed once, or twice?

If it happens once at the beginning, it's much clearer to simply write

```
foo :: IO ()
foo = do
  x <- putStrLn "x generated here" >> return "x used here"
  putStrLn "1"
  putStrLn x
  putStrLn "2"
  putStrLn x
  putStrLn "3"
```

If it's meant to be executed later on, we can move it to the wanted point.

If it's meant to be run twice, we can write

```
foo :: IO ()
foo = do
  x1 <- generateX
  putStrLn "1"
  putStrLn x1
  putStrLn "2"
  x2 <- generateX
  putStrLn x2
  putStrLn "3"
 where
  generateX = putStrLn "x generated here" >> return "x used here"
```

(or, for more readability, use `let` instead of `where`)

In the above code, it is obvious that `generateX` is being run twice, at precise points.

Allowing `where x <- ...` makes the execution unclear. Instead, `do` makes it precise.

Indeed, the whole syntax of `do` blocks can be rewritten in terms of the monadic operations `>>=` and `return`, which guarantee an unambiguous ordering of IO actions.

In principle, one could extend Haskell and define `where x <- ...`, allowing it at least in some cases, but there seems to be nothing to gain doing that, and something to lose about code clarity.